# Concatenated string column is not displaying properly in dropdown list(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is my query which is in Storedprocedure(SQL Server 2008) will return list of items from a table.

Query:

```
SELECT 
( COALESCE(ReviewDescription,'')+ REPLICATE (' ', 20 - LEN(ReviewDescription))
+ '|' + 
( CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),ReviewCharge))) AS ReviewTypes
FROM ReviewType
```

query result(copied to text pad then its looking like below):

```
Sample review type    |200
```

But after binding to ASP drop down control it is displaying like below
drop down display:

```
Sample review type|200
```

Please some one can help on this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it could well just be the browser collapsing whitespace. Look in the HTML source to see what's *actually* being sent down. Then you can determine whether it's a problem in the display or the data access.

(I'm not sure this is really a good way of displaying a pseudo-table in a drop-down, to be honest.)

Comment: I verified in View Source of HTML it is displaying fine but in the Drop Down same issue. I think it is not a Browser issue also, if it is it should remove the spaces between the words.

Comment: @VinnaKanna: Okay, so you need to work out the appropriate HTML to display. (In other words, this is really not HTML problem, rather than one in C# or SQL.) You can experiment with that with a simple text editor and a static HTML file. For example, you might try using `&nbsp;` instead of each space. I'm still not sure it'll look nice, but it might do what you need.